# Calculating center-of-mass enegies for processes/reactions

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, inertial-frames

Let's take any arbitrary process: $d\overline{d}\rightarrow g$.

Let's say I am interested in the center-of-mass energy at which the process can take place. How can I calculate it for any given process?

**Idea(s):**
(i) Use the Mandelstam variable $s: \sqrt{s} = \sqrt{\left( p_d + p_{\overline d} \right)^2}$. We know that $E_d=\sqrt{m^2_a+p^2_a}\Rightarrow E^2_d= m^2_d + p^2_d\Leftrightarrow p^2_d = E^2_d-m^2_d$. Setting $E^2_d = 0$, we obtain $p^2_d = -m^2_d$.

(ii) Now I would also calculate the energy of the right side of the process by ignoring its four momentum, i.e., $E^2_g = m^2_g + p^2_g\overset{p_g=0}{=} m^2_g$.

Then I would compare the values of (i) and (ii) and according to which value is bigger, I would choose it as the center-of-mass energy.

**Question(s)**:

- Is this correct?
- What if I had a process like $a+b\rightarrow c+d$, how would (ii) look like? I guess it would be $E^2 = m^2_c + m^2_d$.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not correct. Any center of mass energy can be found by adding the four vectors of the particles , in this case your $d\overline{d}$, and getting the length of this four vector, i.e. the invariant mass of the system. That is the unique energy  center of mass, no choosing. See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html . If you want the momenta for many body systems you use Lorenz transformations to get them. For two body energy momentum and angular momentum conservation make life simple.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the idea of the link yet. They write (at the very end) that from $s$, we can determine the value of $p^{\star}c$. But how do I know $s$ then?

Comment: The definition of s is given a page before,it is a recipe to get the β and  γ  of the lorenz transformation, if you need to lorenz transform